# How to test `verify` of an express middleware in Jest

Tags: express, jestjs

I have a function which returns a middleware as such:

```js
const jsonParser = () => {
  return express.json({
    limit: '5mb',
    verify: (req, res, buf) => {
      // If the incoming request is a stripe event,
      if (req.headers['some-header']) {
        httpContext.set('raw-body', buf.toString());
      }
    },
  });
};
```

I would like to test that the `httpContext.set`is indeed called when the `some-header` header is present.

My test:

```js
describe('jsonParser middleware', () => {
  it('sets the http context', async () => {
    const req = {
      headers: {
        'some-header': 'some-sig',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        some: 'thing',
      }),
    };

    const res = {};
    const middleware = jsonParser();

    middleware(req, res, () => {});

    expect(httpContext.set).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I have no idea how to make the test run the function passed to `verify`. Express docs state that the content type should be json, but nothing more. Anyone that can point me in the right direction is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't test that at the unit level (as you've seen you end up making test doubles of Express objects whose interface you don't own), use e.g. SuperTest to _integration_ test that endpoints using that header behave correctly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That is a fair point. We are currently lacking integration tests, and this is another good example of why we need it for our higher ups. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments i want to give you an example of an integration test which tests the header and jsonwebtoken. i am also using the express framework but i wrote my code in JS.

this is a test for creating a forumpost in a forum i built. a middleware is checking for the token of the user so this case could be similiar to yours.

```
const request = require('supertest');

test('create authorized 201', async () => {
  const forumCountBefore = await ForumPost.countDocuments();
  const response = await request(app)
    .post('/api/forumPosts')
    .set({
      Authorization: `Bearer ${forumUserOne.tokens[0].token}`,
      userData: {
        userId: forumUserOneId,
        email: 'forum@controller.com',
        username: 'forum',
      },
    })
    .send(forumPost)
    .expect(201);
  expect(response.body.message).toBe('created forumPost');

  const forumCountAfter = await ForumPost.countDocuments();
  expect(forumCountBefore + 1).toBe(forumCountAfter);
});
```

i am using mongoDB thats why i use ForumPost.countDocuments to count the amount of entries in the DB.

as you can see in the test i use supertest (imported as request) to send an http call. in the set block i set the authorization token. this causes the middleware to be executed in the integration test.

the test can only pass when the code of the middleware gets executed correctly so it should cover the code of your middleware.

Comment: I think you are absolutely right. Writing more of an integration-type test for this makes a lot of sense. I am not sure why I was so fixated on writing a unit test for it. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. 

What I ended up doing is modifying res.locals in my middleware. Inspecting whether res.locals contains my desired attributes after a request with supertest is very simple. Thanks again.

Comment: glad i could help :)